# Category pie diagram meta box in post editing page

Tags: categories, jquery, metabox

I am trying to build a plugin for showing a pie diagram based on the number of those categories which have maximum posts. This diagram is a meta box in post editing page. Here is my source of inspiration: [jquery charts](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/displaying-wordpress-site-data-via-jquery-charts/)

Most of the way the function works is same but I added some hooks to add it into meta box.
Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'category_meta_box_add' );

function category_meta_box_add() {  
add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box-id', 'Category by Percentage', 'categories', 'post', 'normal', 'high' ); }  

function categories($atts,$content = '') { }        //full function is defined in link above
add_shortcode('mycategories', 'categories');
echo do_shortcode('[mycategories]');
```

This plugin on installing shows meta box without data, also gives error:

> The plugin generated 721 characters of unexpected output during
>   activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems
>   with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing
>   this plugin.

How to resolve this?

Thanks

Full plugin [here](http://pastebin.com/S3SjVsRz)

Comment: Enable [debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress), look at your logs. You probably have PHP Notices printing before the header are sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be because of this line:

```
echo do_shortcode('[mycategories]');
```

It should not stand alone like this in the plugin file, because this will show up before the headers are sent out. I guess you added this line just to check the output? Try to remove this line or encapsulate it with a relevant function. You could instead add the shortcode `[mycategories]` into the content of some post/page to test it.

You could replace this line

```
add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box-id', 'Category by Percentage', 'categories', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
```

with

```
add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box-id', 'Category by Percentage', 'category_meta_box_html', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
```

and add this function:

```
function category_meta_box_html(){
    echo do_shortcode("[mycategories]");
}
```

to display the graph inside the metabox.

Comment: I have removed that last 2 lines. The error is gone, but I am not able to obtain that pie diagram. Box is present with arrow sign without anything in it. I am not getting how to call this function.

Comment: It gives this error when call this function: categories()
----Warning: Missing argument 1 for categories(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\abcs\wp-content\plugins\infograph\infograph.php on line 86 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\abcs\wp-content\plugins\infograph\infograph.php on line 57-----

Which argument do I pass?

Comment: `categories()` is a callback function for the shortcode, and takes `$atts` and `$content=null` as arguments. I updated the answer, to show you how you could use `do_shortcode` inside the metabox.

Comment: It worked smoothly in localhost, but when I added same into main site, the place is empty. I can't figure it out. :(

Comment: maybe the setup is not the same there, missing .js file? You should check out if there are any javascript errors.

Comment: none, files are on their places. I think maybe wordpress doesn't allow javascript in admin backend due to security. What do you say?

Comment: You could try http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts to enqueue scripts/styles in the backend.

Comment: I switched to google charts, these jqplot files are mess. It works awesome on main site,

Comment: ok good to hear that ;-)